# This Python class variable scope behavior is totally unexpected and frankly weird. What's going on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, scope, multiprocessing

Ok, this one has me tearing my hair out:

I have a multi-process program, with separate workers each working on a given task.

When a KeyboardInterrupt comes, I want each worker to save its internal state to a file, so it can continue where it left off next time.

HOWEVER...

It looks like the dictionary which contains information about the state is vanishing before this can happen!

How? The exit() function is accessing a more globally scoped version of the dictionary... and it turns out that the various run() (and subordinate to run()) functions have been creating their own version of the variable.

Nothing strange about that...

Except...

All of them have been using the self. keyword.

Which, if my understanding is correct, should mean they are always accessing the instance-wide version of the variable... not creating their own!

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
import multiprocessing
import atexit
import signal
import sys
import json

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, my_string_1, my_string_2):
        # Inherit the __init_ from Process, very important or we will get errors
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Make sure we know what to do when called to exit
        atexit.register(self.exit)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit)
        self.my_dictionary = {
            'my_string_1' : my_string_1,
            'my_string_2' : my_string_2
            }
    def run(self):
        self.my_dictionary = {
            'new_string' : 'Watch me make weird stuff happen!'
            }
        try:
            while True:
                print(self.my_dictionary['my_string_1'] + " " + self.my_dictionary['my_string_2'])
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            self.exit()
    def exit(self):
        # Write the relevant data to file
        info_for_file = {
            'my_dictionary': self.my_dictionary
            }
        print(info_for_file) # For easier debugging
        save_file = open('save.log', 'w')
        json.dump(info_for_file, save_file)
        save_file.close()
        # Exit
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    strings_list = ["Hello", "World", "Ehlo", "Wrld"]
    instances = []
    try:
        for i in range(len(strings_list) - 2):
            my_string_1 = strings_list[i]
            my_string_2 = strings_list[i + 1]
            instance = Worker(my_string_1, my_string_2)
            instances.append(instance)
            instance.start()
        for instance in instances:
            instance.join()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        for instance in instances:
            instance.exit()
            instance.close()
```

On run we get the following traceback...

```
Process Worker-2:
Process Worker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in run
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in run
KeyError: 'my_string_1'
KeyError: 'my_string_1'
```

In other words, even though the key my_string_1 was explicitly added during **init**, the run() function is accessing a new version of self.my_dictionary which does not contain that key!

Again, this would be expected if we were dealing with a normal variable (my_dictionary instead of self.my_dictionary) but I thought that self.variables were always instance-wide...

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can basically be represented by the following:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def run(self):
        self.x = 2

        if self.x != 1:
            print("self.x isn't 1!")

t = Test()
t.run()
```

Note what `run` is doing.

You overwrite your instance member `self.my_dictionary` with incompatible data when you write

```
self.my_dictionary = {
            'new_string' : 'Watch me make weird stuff happen!'
}
```

Then try to use that incompatible data when you say

```
print(self.my_dictionary['my_string_1']...
```

It's not clear precisely what your intent is when you overwrite `my_dictionary`, but that's why you're getting the error. You'll need to rethink your logic.

Comment: Thanks, I think you got it, and you're correct my code could have been more minimal... I wasn't sure if the multiprocessing aspect might be part of the problem.

I was meaning to set self.my_dictionary["new_string"] = 'Watch me make weird stuff happen!' ...

Making that correction in the original demo code produces the expected result.

Unfortunately, making the same correction in the original program doesn't! I still get a 'schitzophrenic variable' effect where the data run() adds to the dictionary is not there when the program exits...

Comment: @right2clicky You must be doing something similar elsewhere. Put simply, the effect you're describing doesn't just happen on its own. Try to find where your demo differs.

Comment: Well, I searched the code for the equivalent variable to self.my_dictionary, and here's what I do to it:
__init__: gets initialized to {} ...
body function: len() ...
body function: .append(somedata) ...
body function: .pop(index) ...
body function: .extend(somedata) ...

...as well as some things to get data from the variable. That's it!

And I have no idea how any of those would clobber or overwrite it...

Comment: @right2clicky I guess you are confusing the copy of the worker in the main process with the copy in the spawned processes somehow.